# Блокировка запросов, содержащих определенную подстроку в url

Tags: linux, nginx, сервер

Сайт атакуется с вирусного плагина, загруженного на другие сайты (DDOS). В логах доступа `nginx` записаны url-адреса, с которых производится атака; эти адреса содержат одну повторяющуюся подстроку. Можно ли как-то на сервере настроить блокировку запросов по наличию этой подстроки в адресе, с которого переходят на сайт?

Comment: `failregex` в https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04 ?

Answer (score 1):

Можете проверять наличие строки в $http_referrer переменной и отдавать 403 или 444 коды ответа например так:

```
if ($http_referrer = "some_url") {
    return 444;
}
```

Заголовок Referrer конечно легко сделать другим, но предложенное решение лежит на поверхности.